# How to switch between source code debug mode and disassembly debug mode in LLDB

Tags: xcode, lldb

How to switch between source code debug mode and disassembly debug mode in LLDB，like "Xcode->Debug->Debug Workflow->Always show disassembly" menu function?

Answer (score 13):

These four settings control how lldb displays source/assembly when you stop:

```
  stop-disassembly-count   -- The number of disassembly lines to show when displaying a stopped context.
  stop-disassembly-display -- Control when to display disassembly when displaying a stopped context.
  stop-line-count-after    -- The number of sources lines to display that come after the current source line when displaying a stopped context.
  stop-line-count-before   -- The number of sources lines to display that come before the current source line when displaying a stopped context.
```

So for instance, at the LLDB prompt:

```
set set stop-disassembly-display always
set set stop-line-count-before 0
set set stop-line-count-after 0
```

Will only display assembly.

Comment: There's a sample command in the lldb sources: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/python/disassembly_mode.py that toggles between this "convenient for assembly" mode and "convenient for source" mode, if you do that sort of thing a lot.

Comment: corrected url : https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/lldb/examples/python/disassembly_mode.py